# I need help finding a car

Tags: car

I am seventeen years old.  I have have a job but I only make a little money.

I am trying to get a car for my senior year of high school but I only have about $400 saved up.  I have to pay other people for gas (about $25 a week).

I have a month to save enough  to get a cheap used car but I don’t know how I’ll be able to do so. What should I do?

Comment: How much are you earning per month? Would you have to pay all the associated expenses like insurance/maintenance/fuel?

Comment: If this is in the USA, you can easily buy a perfectly good used car for say 500$. Start with "cars.com" and also "craigslist.org".  (Be aware that 1/3 of the listings on craigslist are just scams, buyt the rest are just your neighbors selling old cars.)  Also just ask all local mechanics, they'll be happy to help.

Answer (score 7):

Depending on your local area, you could potentially find a rusty beater in your local area in the $400-$800 range, which would technically run. I've used  Craigslist (make sure you read about how to avoid scams, cash-in-hand in-person transactions only, etc), and others have told me equivalents like Facebook Marketplace can be a good source as well.

In this price range you should expect you will have to continually put money into the car in repairs, even if it technically runs on its own (perhaps loudly and clunkily). My personal rule of thumb is a car that runs with any reliability runs around $2000 - you can pay that in advance to get a car in that condition, or you can pay it over time buy buying a cheaper, worse condition car and investing in improvements.

When I was as poor as I ever have been (and hopefully ever will be, jeeze was I broke), I learned some basic auto repair and maintenance via YouTube to make it a little cheaper to have a car I was going to drive until it died. You can search for things like "change oil [year] [make] [model]" and there is usually someone kindly walking you through the process. When you are really broke and really desperate to have a car to get where you need to go, you can amaze yourself at what you can learn (and put up with).

Regardless, some things you won't be able to do (or which inevitably cost more money), and so if you go down this route you'll have to put away money continually every month towards repairs. I estimate you'll end up paying $100-200 a month with this class of car on average repairs throughout the first year, if you are fortunate and purchased wisely. I also once had a van I bought for $250...it lasted for almost exactly 5 weeks before it blew a head gasket. Well, it was cheaper than renting a car, I guess.

However, since you are new to cars, you must know this isn't the only expense (and gas isn't either). Ever state has their own "tax, title, and tag" fees to register your car and get plates on it. Some states are cheap for older cars, and you can get going with under $100...in some states its more like $300 or more. You basically pay this to your local DMV-equivalent right away, before you can meaningfully drive anywhere.

Similarly, you will be required to maintain insurance. Go without this and you will very quickly find yourself out of a license and with a few thousand dollars in tickets. This also varies by state, and bad news - while you are under 25 or 30 the cost is so high that when you see it you'll probably say "oh come the #%$@ on!" This will be a little cheaper if your parents/guardians let you be added onto their insurance, but even then I know when my first kid started driving my insurance went up over $100 a month. You can get a free quote from insurance companies (Esurance, Progressive, GEICO, whatever - any company you've heard of will get you a free quote online in a few minutes). If you can't be on someone else's policy...well, I doubt you can get away with less than $100 a month, but you should check and see.

And in the end? With a car this cheap, you run on borrowed time. Never know when the poor thing is going to die on you, it was already almost certainly at the end of its life (or past) when you got it.

If you want to have a better shot at a more reasonable car, in areas of the US I'm familiar with you'll need closer to the $2000 range to get a car that you could reasonably hope will run a few years without too much immediate work from you.

My suggestion? I'll tell you what I tell my own kids: when you don't have much money, cars mostly make sure you will have even less. Try to find a way to do without one while you build your savings. Ride share with friends at school (gas is a small price to pay), school bus, local transit system bus (even if you have to walk a ways to the nearest stop), etc. This assumes it is too far or dangerous to walk/bike, of course - because that's waaay cheaper.

Focus on not merely finishing high school, but doing well. Don't let the end of the school day be the end of your education - hell, for many people the end of the school day must be the **start** of your education, because not every school teaches all that much. Work hard at your job, even if it sucks, and keep an eye out for better opportunities. Demand what little money you have now give you things you genuinely value and appreciate, and when you have more money take that lesson with you - it makes all the difference in the world.

Compare you alternatives, with and without a car, and write down what you find for options. If you decide to buy, look at many dozens of options before you even bother to try to go look at one in person, so you get to learn the market of what people offer. Work to spot scams early, figure out how not to get suckered (listen to your gut if it warns you something is off).

Once you have these many options available to you, then - and only then - will you have the chance and ability to choose wisely. This may mean getting a car, or not - that'll be up to you, the options you find, and what you value.

Oh, one last bit of advice - if someone tries to steer you into some kind of "buy here pay here" el cheapo used car place because they approve you guaranteed, blah blah blah, get the heck out of there. Pretty well universally (99.99%) a bunch of predatory thieves, and a great way to end up with no car, no money, and phoney debt on top of it.

Comment: Thank you this helped a lot I will talk all of this advice into consideration.